# Disable Printing Issue with PDF Box

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, printing, pdfbox

I am using this [sample PDFBox code](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/encryption.html) to encrypt and disable printing of a pdf file. Encryption happens successfully, but printing is not disabled.

What could be the issue?

Here's the dependencies section of my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and below is the source code

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardProtectionPolicy;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("/tmp/Test.pdf"));
        int keyLength = 128;
        AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
        ap.setCanPrint(false);
        StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("Admin", "Password", ap);
        spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);
        spp.setPermissions(ap);
        doc.protect(spp);
        doc.save("/tmp/Test-Encrypted.pdf");
        doc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What password did you use to open the file with Adobe Reader - "Admin" or "Password"? If you used "Admin" then you have all rights (owner password).

Comment: I used **Password**. Also I am not using Adobe Reader. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Another thing to try: call also `setCanPrintDegraded(false)`.

Comment: It depends whether the application respects the setting. Adobe PDF security isn't real security. So please test with Adobe.

Comment: *Also I am not using Adobe Reader. Could that be a problem?* - so what do you test with?

Comment: @mkl - I use https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince

Comment: evince [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/ComparingEvinceAcroread) currently admits that *security* features need improvement ("Advanced Functions", item 4). Thus, you should not assume its behavior e.g. concerning permissions to be according to spec.